# How to remove 'home' in wagtail URLs

Tags: wagtail

I have a wagtail project with a 'Home' page at root  (slug='home').

There is a second page 'Blog' which is a child of 'Home' (slug='blog').

Finally, I have blog-posting pages which are children of 'Blog' (slug='blog-post-1' etc.).

In `blog/models.py` I have the following code:

```
class BlogListingPage(Page):
    """List the Blog detail pages."""

    template = "blog/blog_listing_page.html"
    ....
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Add custom content to our context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['blog_pages'] = self.get_children().live()
        return context


class BlogDetailPage(Page):
    """Blog detail page."""
    template = "blog/blog_detail_page.html"
    ....
```

To access the blog I use:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
```

And that works perfectly.

Now, the URLs for the detail pages are `/home/blog/blog-post-1/` etc, but the page is really located at `/blog/blog-post-1/`.

Where is the '/home' coming from and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: How are you outputting the page URLs? (Are you using `page.url_path`, by any chance?)

Comment: @gasman Yes! How did you guess?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're outputting the page URL using `{{ page.url_path }}`. This is an internal field of the `Page` object, and isn't intended to be used directly as the page URL (because that will depend on where the site root has been placed, under Settings -> Sites) - rather, Wagtail calculates the final URL as the difference between the target page's `url_path` (`/home/blog/blog-post-1/` here) and the root page's `url_path` (`/home/`).

The correct way to specify a page URL in a template is: `{% pageurl page %}`. (You'll also need `{% load wagtailcore_tags %}` at the top of your template.)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. In my html:     {% for post in blog_pages %}
        {% pageurl post %}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have `'/home'` in `urls.py`.  If you do, replace it with `''`.  The last line in `urls.py` would typically be:

```
urlpatterns.append(path('', include(wagtail_urls)))
```

Also, in the Wagtail admin, in Settings -> Sites, make sure you've chosen the root page for your site.